# Neo4J libary methods are not available after installation

Tags: database, neo4j

I installed two plugins in neo4j desktop. I try do operated with the methods then. But I did not worked. Have anybody an idea why?
[image: Foto Installation]

[image]

Comment: What is the code you're trying to run? Please add that to the question!

Comment: So after installing GDS, you cannot run gds shortestPath.  Can you click on the button "List Available Procedures" on your 2nd screen shot? What functions/procedures do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to restart your database, and you can check eg. with `return apoc.version()` or `return gds.version()` if the plugins are installed.

For APOC you can use `call apoc.help("")` to see the installed/available procedures and functions.

Generally you can use `SHOW PROCEDURES` and `SHOW FUNCTIONS`.